# Real bitcoin buying versus forex speculation

Tags: exchange-rate, ethereum, price-volatility, stocks

so I had a discussion with the colleges today and I would that my arguments would be verified here.

1. Basically the question is **what are the differences between buying and selling real cryptocurrencies at cryptocurrencies stocks** or cantors and making "positions" on stock exchanges, forex etc.

I personally don't see any reason to play stock exchanges rather than doing so on real cryptocurrency system. For the gold I see the pragmatism and comfort, since there would be hard to transfering gold and would be a bit of risky, but for cryptocurrencies in my opinion is a nonsense.

2. The other question is **if speculation on stock exchanges have an impact of the value of real cryptocurrencies** ?

As I believe the real cryptocurrency value is determined JUST on cryptocurrencies stocks where people are selling and buying real bitcoins etc using blockchains ! As this I feel closer to the law of supply and demand. I believe that speculation value is not a real one and is often distorted, as some people bet something (which can be true or not). And I believe that something is worth that much as someone would like to pay for.

At most I can agree that values on stock exchanges can have an psychological impact for the people who are following mass media and the stock exchanges and based on that information they want to trade real cryptocurrencies if they do suddenly, instead of gambling stocks. If they just gamble on stock this does not have an impact at all in my opinion.

**Please someone can tell if I am wrong or right ? And give an argument for that.**

---

And **the whole story** is more or less like this:

Lets say, I am a bitcoin enthusiast. So I met the guy who is speculator with few years of experience, he plays in stock exchanges and is interested in bitcoins, but actually do not know how they works. But I do not know how the stock exchanges works as well. So there is possibility that I am wrong.

So, he told that the ethereum price get lost in his stock exchange for a minute down to 1 $. This was caused by someone who have finished his "position", so as I understand someone who had lots of ethereum coins decided to sell them at once, so he satisfied all the needs on this stock exchange so there was a lot of ethereum coins available to buy, while no people willing buy coins for that quick moment. This caused lost of value of ethereum IN THE STOCK EXCHANGE. This could be true information since he show me some article from some stock exchange news web page.

And for that story I have said that for me this is not important at all. Because I believe in the value which is described by the real forces of supply and demand of REAL CRYPTOCURRENCIES. So in my opinion REAL VALUE of REAL ETHEREUM have not went down at all even for this minute. Because all the guys who have been bet / gambling / playing on stock have never had any true / real ethereum.

As I understand situation they just transfered the money to the stock. Then make a "position" so nothing more like an entry JUST in that stock exchange, on which they converted the real currency into ethereum / bitcoin / gold / other real currency. But as I believe they never had any value in real blockchain, they can't pay anything by ethereum and they never could and never would be able until they buy real crypto currency. So they can just convert back this entry in that stock exchange and get back real money (less or more depended on their gambling score).

Because of that this operation (selling lots of ehtereum in some stock exchange) does not have any impact on real ethereum value, neither on cryptocurrencies stocks like bit bay etc.

Another friend starting to saying what if the current monetary system would fall down.. But this is an argument for my theory too ! Because if the system fall down while I would have real bitcoins written into blockchain and my friend would have an entry in his stock exchange. Then he can get back his dollars, but they would be worthless. And I would still be able to transfer a value. Then I heard an argument about the world get lost electricity but this scenario I just skipped..